# How to read all the worksheets in a Excel file

Tags: vb6

I have an excel file which contains 7 to 8 worksheets(sheet1,sheet2 ....), i want to read all the sheets one by one.Can somebody suggest me how to achieve this in VB6.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [WorkSheets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa224508%28v=office.11%29.aspx) collection. It has a `Count` property that contains the number of workshees, and you can access sheet `2` via `Worksheets(2)` - you don't need to know the name of the sheet.